# Tomar parametro en una url y enviarlo al modelo cuando se envie un form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Tengo una vista `CreateView` a la que le estoy pasando una PK por la URL, 
lo que quiero hacer basicamente es tomar esa PK y mandarla a un campo del modelo con el que trabaja esta vista (el formulario no contiene el campo del modelo al que le quiero pasar la PK, porque precisamente quiero tomarlo de la URL y mandarlo al modelo sin que introduzca el valor por el `form`).

Esta es la vista:

```
class EventTrackingCreateView(CreateView):
    model = EventTracking
    template_name = 'tracking/form/form.html'
    form_class = EventTrackingForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventTrackingCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('events.list')

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(EventTrackingCreateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

La URL de la vista:

```
url(r'^tracking/create/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(views.EventTrackingCreateView.as_view()), name='events.tracking.create'),
```

El modelo: (la PK debe guardarse en el campo `event`)

```
class EventTracking(TimeStampedModel):
    type = models.ForeignKey(TypeEventTracking, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('tipo de seguimiento'))
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('evento'))
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_('Descripcion'), validators=[MinLengthValidator(20)])
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name="user_profile_created", verbose_name="_('creado_por)", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name="user_profile_updated", verbose_name="_('actualizado_por)", on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Seguimiento de Evento')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Seguimiento de Eventos')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(EventTracking, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

A esta vista se está ingresando por medio de un enlace de esta forma:

```
<a href="{% url 'events.tracking.create' event.id %}">Crear seguimiento</a>
```

Cabe resaltar que tengo un modelo llamado `Event` como ya se ha podido ver, al cual le quiero asociar un tracking, en el formulario solo renderizo los campos `type` y `description`.

Estuve leyendo un poco sobre el metodo `get_object` que me pareció que es el que más se acerca a solucionar el problema que tengo, no se si estoy en lo cierto.

Comment: También, ¿qué versión de Django estás usando?

Comment: Hola @César estoy trabajando con la versión 1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es sencillo, te recomendaré una página para que busques información acerca de las CBV (Class Based Views).

En tu vista, cuando envías parámetros por url, y los capturas con la expresión regular, los puedes obtener desde la vista con `self.kwargs`, y si lo que quieres es enviarlo a tu formulario, te recomiendo usar el método `get_form_kwargs` para enviarlo, de esta forma:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    # ahora puedes recuperar tu pk o id
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    # y lo envias al formulario, no se como esperas recibirlo en el formulario, pero si en el init aceptas un pk, lo envias así.
    kwargs['pk'] = pk
    return kwargs
```

Yo te recomendaría enviarlo por formulario, para que sea un solo golpe a la base de datos, y seria mas seguro, pero como quieres guardarlo directamente, la solución seria esta:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    success = super().form_valid(form)
    # aqui asignas
    self.object.campo_asignar = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    self.object.save()
    return success
```

Cualquier pregunta, comenta

Comment: Al usar `super().form_valid(form)`, ¿se está guardando en la base de datos el objeto? Si es así, me parece que estarías haciendo doble trabajo al volver a guardar en la base de datos cuando se podría hacer de una sola vez.

Comment: Si, de hecho, eso lo comente, que se hace mas de un golpe a la base de datos... de otro modo, estas reescribiendo código, por eso lo ideal es hacerlo desde el formulario, ademas que siempre será mejor para hacer pruebas, y para mantener todas las validaciones juntas

Comment: @César es que en tu respuesta veo, que estas reescribiendo el método `post` y tu mismo estas haciendo el render, a este punto, se hace mas controlable el hecho de crear una FBV y no una CBV

Comment: Pues justamente una de las características de la programación orientada a objetos es el la capacidad de poder sobreescribir las funciones de las clases padre. Como yo lo veo, prefiero sobreescribir un método (que no me quita performance) a realizar doble escritura en la base de datos.

Comment: Hola, @GermanAlzate, gracias por tu respuesta, implemente el método form_valid de dos maneras pero ninguna funciono, hice una respuesta expllicando como las implemente, si ves algo que esta mal serias tan amable de comentarlo, mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

La clase [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) hereda de varias clases incluyendo el mixin [`ProcessFormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ProcessFormView). Lo que puedes intentar es sobreescribir el método `post` de esta última clase:

```
class EventTrackingCreateView(CreateView):

    # ...

    @property
    def event_id(self):
        return self.kwargs.get('pk') # El que estás pasando en tu URL

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            event_tracking = form.save(commit=False)
            event_tracking.event_id = self.event_id
            event_tracking.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Estoy usando una propiedad `event_id` que simplemente te retorna el PK que estás pasando desde tu URL. Al pasar el parámetro `commit=False` al método `save` del formulario le estás diciendo que no guarde el objeto en la base de datos. Aprovechando esto último guardamos el PK del evento y finalmente lo guardas explícitamente llamando al método `save` del objeto.

Comment: Hola @Cesar, hice una respuesta explicando como resolví el problema por ahora pero no es la solución que quería implementar, también explique como implemente el método post para que porfa lo veas y me digas si hay algo que deba modificar, te agradezco